# Fiddler ServerDoneResponse vs GotResponseHeaders

Tags: http, https, fiddler

I am looking at fiddler statistics below is my result: 
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
    ClientConnected:    13:37:48.551
    ClientBeginRequest: 13:37:49.281
    GotRequestHeaders:  13:37:49.281
    ClientDoneRequest:  13:37:49.283
    Determine Gateway:  0ms
    DNS Lookup:         0ms
    TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
    HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
    ServerConnected:    13:37:48.708
    FiddlerBeginRequest:    13:37:49.283
    ServerGotRequest:   13:37:49.284
    ServerBeginResponse:    13:37:49.627
    GotResponseHeaders: 13:37:49.627
    ServerDoneResponse: 13:38:25.833
    ClientBeginResponse:    13:38:25.835
    ClientDoneResponse: 13:38:25.872
    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:36.590

As you see, ServerDoneResponse minus GotResponseHeaders, seems to be time required for client to get response from server. 
I have checked ServerDoneResponse means "Exact time that Fiddler got the first bytes of the server's HTTP response. " 
ServerDoneResponse - Exact time that Fiddler got the last bytes of the server's HTTP response.
From URL = http://fiddler.wikidot.com/timers 
But it does not mentions me about GotResponseHeaders ? 
So my understanding is, for getting response from server to client it has taken most of the time i.e. ServerBeginResponse: 13:37:49.627 minus ServerDoneResponse: 13:38:25.833 ? Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any documentation for this but I think 'GotResponseHeaders' is the time when Fiddler starts getting the response back from the server. Not necessarily that the response has been completed at that time. To confirm this, I did a few tests with scenarios mentioned below:

1. Added a delay at server side code so that it starts the response a little later.
2. Downloaded a 10MB file so that it takes some time for the response to complete.

In the first case when I added a delay before responding, 'ServerBeginResponse' was delayed too and 'GotResponseHeaders' was same as 'ServerBeginResponse'. This suggests that Fiddler got the response at the same time server started responding(again, it's not necessary that the response has been completed).

for the second case too, 'GotResponseHeaders' was same as 'ServerBeginResponse' suggesting 'GotResponseHeaders' is the time when Fiddler started receiving the response. Note that since the file download took some time, 'ServerDoneResponse' was delayed by few seconds.

In above case, if ServerDoneResponse minus GotResponseHeaders is taking long then you should check the size of the response and also the network latency.